# Blocked frame after htaccess implementation

Tags: javascript, html, css, .htaccess

I have created a tool and more specifically an ***HTML/CSS editor with a live preview***.

[LINK](http://www.apolosiskos.co.uk/HTML-CSS-EDITOR/%5bB-Dat002%5d/index.html)

Yesterday, I added an `.htaccess` file on the server and today I was getting an error :

[image]

The content of the `.htaccess` file is shown below :

```
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent "^wget" bad_bot
<Limit GET POST>
   Order Allow,Deny
   Allow from all
   Deny from env=bad_bot
</Limit>
```

Then I tried this link (which is the same basically the same link) :

[LINK 2](http://www.apolosiskos.co.uk/HTML-CSS-EDITOR/%5BB-Dat002%5D/index.html)

The diffrent parts of the link urls are shown below :

- /%5bB-Dat002%5d/
- /%5BB-Dat002%5D/

I tried opening the links in incognito mode and both links worked. Is this issue related to the `.htaccess` file and my chrome cookies? I cannot find the cause of this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was related to the provider (host). It has been resolved :)